# Como saber el tipo de dato de un vector en c++

Tags: c++

estaba haciendo un programa que valide si los tipos de datos ingresados en una función son iguales. Entonces al inicio lo hice con sizeof, pero luego cuando ingresaba vectores con diferentes tipos de dato me retornaba que eran iguales. Entonces ¿Cómo puedo validar el tipo de dato de un vector?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<typename i, typename k>
bool razon(){
    if (sizeof(i)==sizeof(k))
      return true;
    else
      return false;
}
```

Esta es la función plantilla que cree.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Debes tener en cuenta que dos punteros van a tener siempre el mismo tamaño apunten al tipo de dato que apunten, por lo que tu código va a devolver siempre `true`. Por otro lado, dado un puntero, no existe ninguna "firma" que identifique un tipo de dato u otro a partir de únicamente el puntero. Si deseas hacer ese tipo de comparaciones, guarda el tipo de dato en alguna parte junto con el puntero al dato.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma sería usando `is_same` y `decltype` de la STL:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> a, b;
    vector<double> c;
    
    cout << is_same<decltype(a), decltype(b)>::value << endl; // output: 1
    cout << is_same<decltype(a), decltype(c)>::value << endl; // output: 0

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes encontrar más información en la documentación: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same

Espero ayude.

Answer (score 2):

En primer lugar, debes entender que una plantilla con tipos irrestrictos puede aceptar cualquier tipo, así que usando tu plantilla `razon` obtendremos `true` en todos estos casos:

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha
    << razon<int, unsigned>() << '\n'       // true
    << razon<int, char[4]>() << '\n'        // true
    << razon<long long, int[2]>() << '\n';  // true
```

Y en ninguno de los casos hemos facilitado un vector para ambos parámetros. Si quieres comprobar los tipos de formaciones<sup>1</sup> la plantilla debe ser diferente:

```
template <typename A, typename B, auto sz_A, auto sz_B>
bool razon(const A(&)[sz_A], const B(&)[sz_B])
{
    return false;
}

template <typename A, auto sz_A, auto sz_B>
bool razon(const A(&)[sz_A], const A(&)[sz_B])
{
    return true;
}
```

Tenemos dos versiones de una plantilla que recibe como referencia constante una formación<sup>1</sup>, en una de las versiones el tipo del primer argumento es diferente al tipo del segundo y obviamente devuelve `false`, en la otra versión ambos argumentos son el mismo y obviamente devuelve `true`:

```
int       i10[10]{};
unsigned  u10[10]{};
int       i20[20]{};
char      c4[4]{};
long long ll[10]{};
int       i2[2]{};

std::cout << std::boolalpha
    << razon(i10, u10) << '\n' // false (int vs unsigned)
    << razon(i20, c4) << '\n'  // false (int vs char)
    << razon(ll, i2) << '\n';  // false (long long vs int)
```

Si quieres que además coincida el tamaño puedes modificar la segunda versión:

```
template <typename A, auto sz_A, auto sz_B>
bool razon(const A(&)[sz_A], const A(&)[sz_B])
{
    return sz_A == sz_B;
}

// ...

std::cout << std::boolalpha
    << razon(i10, i10) << '\n' // true (int[10] vs int[10])
    << razon(i10, i20) << '\n'; // false (int[10] vs int[20])
```

Si te referías a `std::vector` no a formaciones<sup>1</sup>, la plantilla debería ser algo así:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
bool razon(const std::vector<A> &, const std::vector<B> &)
{
    return false;
}

template <typename A>
bool razon(const std::vector<A> &, const std::vector<A> &)
{
    return true;
}

std::vector<int>       vi;
std::vector<unsigned>  vu;
std::vector<char>      vc;
std::vector<long long> vll;

// ...

std::cout << std::boolalpha
    << razon(vi, vu) << '\n'  // false
    << razon(vi, vc) << '\n'  // false
    << razon(vll, vi) << '\n' // false
    << razon(vi, vi) << '\n'  // true
    << razon(vc, vc) << '\n'; // true
```

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *array*.